# How to navigate back to home button from my last page

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch-2

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ui.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    config: {
        fullscreen: true,

            layout: {
                type: 'card',
                animation: {
                    type: 'slide',


                }

            },
            items: [

/************** panel home ***************/

            {    
             xtype: 'panel',
             id:'homePanel',            
             layout: {
                type: 'card',
                animation: {
                    type: 'slide'                                   
                }
             },
             items : [      
                    {
                    xtype: 'panel',                
                    items : [{
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    items : [
                     {
                        xtype: 'image',
                        docked: 'left',
                        html: '<div class="applogo"><img src="../images/logo.png"/></div>',
                        ui: 'light'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        docked: 'right',
                        html: '<img src="../images/about_us.png"/>',
                        id: 'BtnInfo',
                        itemId: 'BtnInfo',
                        style: '',
                          handler:function(){                           
                            Ext.getCmp('homePanel').setActiveItem('aboutusPanel');      
                                }                                        
                    },


                    ]
                    },


                    { xtype: 'panel',

                        height: 136,    
                        items: [{
                        xtype: 'carousel',
                        id:'HomeCarousel',
                        height: 136,
                        items: [
                                {
                                    title: 'title card 1',
                                    html: '<img src="../images/image_5.png"/>'                                  
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'title card 2',
                                    html: '<img src="../images/image_2.png"/>'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'title card 3',
                                    html: '<img src="../images/image_3.png"/>'
                                },
                                {
                                    title: 'title card 4',
                                    html: '<img src="../images/image_4.png"/>'
                                }
                            ]
                    }],


                    },
                        {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        height: 45,
                        html: '<div class="list_item"><span class="list_icon"><img src="../images/locations.png" align="left"/></span><span class="list_text">Locations</span><span  class="list_forward"><img src="../images/arrow.png" align="right"/></div></span></div>',
                        id: 'BtnLocationsHome',
                        itemId: 'BtnLocationsHome',
                        text: 'Locations',                                              
                             handler:function(){                            
                            Ext.getCmp('homePanel').setActiveItem('locationPanel');     
                                }                                        
                    },




                     {
                          xtype: 'button',
                        height: 45,
                        html: '<div class="list_item"><span class="list_icon"><img src="../images/services.png" align="left"/></span><span class="list_text">Services</span><span  class="list_forward"><img src="../images/arrow.png" align="right"/></span></div>',
                        itemId: 'BtnServices',
                        text: 'Services',
                         handler: function() {
                                Ext.getCmp('homePanel').setActiveItem('servicesPanel');     
                        } 


                    },

                {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        height: 45,
                        html: '<div class="list_item"><span class="list_icon"><img src="../images/downloads.png" align="left"/></span><span class="list_text">Downloads</span><span  class="list_forward"><img src="../images/arrow.png" align="right"/></div></span></div>',
                        id: 'BtnDownloads',
                        itemId: 'BtnDownloads',
                        text: 'Downloads',

                         handler: function() {
                            Ext.getCmp('homePanel').setActiveItem('downloadPanel');     
                         }
                    },

                    {

                        xtype: 'button',
                         height: 45,
                        html: '<div class="list_item"><span class="list_icon"><img src="../images/promotions.png" align="left"/></span><span class="list_text">Promotions</span><span  class="list_forward"><img src="../images/arrow.png" align="right"/></div></span></div>',
                        id: 'BtnPromotions',
                        itemId: 'BtnPromotions',
                        text: 'Promotions',
                         handler: function() {
                            Ext.getCmp('homePanel').setActiveItem('promotionPanel');        
                         }
                    },

                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        height: 45,
                        html: '<div class="list_item"><span class="list_icon"><img src="../images/coupons.png" align="left"/></span><span class="list_text">Coupons</span><span  class="list_forward"><img src="../images/arrow.png" align="right"/></span></div>',
                        itemId: 'BtnCoupons',
                        text: 'Coupons',
                         handler: function() {
                            Ext.getCmp('homePanel').setActiveItem('couponPanel');       
                         }
                    }

                    ]
                }
                ]},

                    /*  home panel end */   


/****************  location **********************/ 
        {
             xtype: 'panel',
             id:'locationPanel',            
             layout: {
                type: 'card',
                animation: {
                    type: 'slide'                                               
                }
             },
             items : [                              
    {
        xtype: 'panel',       

        items : [       

             {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked: 'top',
                ui: 'light',
                title: 'Locations',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        docked: 'left',
                        html: '<img src="../images/back_arrow.png"/>',
                        id: 'BtnBackLoc',
                        itemId: 'BtnBackLoc',
                        handler: function() {                                                
                            Ext.getCmp('homePanel').setActiveItem(0);   
                            //this.getParent().parent.setActiveItem('homePanel')    
                            //Ext.getCmp('locationPanel').setActiveItem(0);                 
                         }
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        docked: 'right',
                        html: '<img src="../images/home.png"/>',
                        id: 'LocationBtnHome',
                        handler: function() {
                            Ext.getCmp('homePanel').setActiveItem(0);   
                         }                       
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel', 

                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        height: 45,
                        html: '<div class="list_item"><span class="list_icon"><img src="../images/locations.png" align="left"/></span><span class="list_text">Showrooms</span><span  class="list_forward"><img src="../images/arrow.png" align="right"/></span></div>',
                        id: 'BtnShowroomLoc',
                        itemId: 'BtnShowroomLoc',
                        handler:function(){
                        Ext.getCmp('locationPanel').setActiveItem('showroomPanel');

                        }
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        height: 45,
                        html: '<div class="list_item"><span class="list_icon"><img src="../images/locations.png" align="left"/></span><span class="list_text">Service Centers</span><span  class="list_forward"><img src="../images/arrow.png" align="right"/></span></div>',
                        id: 'BtnServiceCenterLoc',
                        itemId: 'BtnServiceCenterLoc',
                        handler:function(){
                        Ext.getCmp('locationPanel').setActiveItem('servicecenterPanel');

                        }


                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        height: 45,
                        html: '<div class="list_item"><span class="list_icon"><img src="../images/locations.png" align="left"/></span><span class="list_text">Driving Schools</span><span  class="list_forward"><img src="../images/arrow.png" align="right"/></span></div>',
                        id: 'BtnDriveLoc',
                        itemId: 'BtnDriveLoc',
                        handler:function(){
                        Ext.getCmp('locationPanel').setActiveItem('drivingschoolPanel');

                        }

                    }
                ]
            }

     ]
                }


                ]

                },
                /* panel location end */
```

Comment: Sorry, but you can't post a huge snippet like that with no description/information and expect people to help.

Comment: You want to navigate to specific button or entire panel ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `setActiveItem();`function in your back button handler. In set active item function just mention your home panel.

Comment: i want to use card layout for 3 panels. so after navigating to 3rd panel.  i need to go directly to the home button.             handler: function() {
  Ext.getCmp('homePanel').setActiveItem(0);   
         }                // but using this function i am only able to go to the back link .ie my second panel  not to the home page..

Comment: try to add listeners in your TabPanel and try once with index.